# Different result when generate MD5 hash

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

This is my code:

```
private static string ComputeMD5Hash(string input)
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The result MD5 from my code is: "91c8798099fac8762bb0e014084a3f08".

The result MD5 from online tool is: "8bb25958e7b1caad4a3be362d6098d76".

So, what the problem here? Why I can't get the same result I use .NET 5.

Comment: yes as a mdshash would include the timestamp and random numbeers, you will get with MD5.Create()) every time a new mds hash

Comment: They are the same so what's the question? Although `Encoding.Default` looks suspicious, you should probably decide which encoding to use upfront.

Comment: sorry for that my code result is : 91c8798099fac8762bb0e014084a3f08

Comment: Can you at least provide from what tool and what was the input data ?

Comment: Did the decode result is the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MD5 Hash From String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979212/md5-hash-from-string)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and it produced correct hash (on my machine). I used tool [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=MD5()&input=aGVsbG8) to verify it.

The only problematic part could be the encoding. You have set `Default`. But try to specify `UTF8` instead.